# Login with python requests and SMF cookie

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to Python and requests and I'm trying to login a site with python requests and it seems to work alright at first, but as soon as I use the session and move to another page I keep getting redirected back to the login page (in the python script).

I noticed a similar issue when testing the site with IE 11, but the site works fine with Chrome or Firefox. So I pulled up the Developer tools and compared IE 11 with Chrome and the cookies are different:

IE 11:

> __qca=P0-193635655-1454037632726; PHPSESSID=f4hmvt7cvfrfqg0seivmu34fv7

Chrome:

> __qca=P0-701638259-1453424539435; SMFCookie474=a%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%2299842%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A40%3A%22dc7db4be19f7f4fc53d2411065b8b7bf5705c83a%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A1454036767%3Bi%3A3%3Bi%3A0%3B%7D; PHPSESSID=o43kja5a9iq1b8ibdll5sh2s24

Python Requests:

> PHPSESSID=hotj0fpm5pbipktmm51kirul45

So I would assume I'm missing some cookies with python requests to make this work. Any advice?

```py
def login_test():
    payload = {
        'user': 'user',
        'passwrd': 'pass'
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post('http://www.example.com/SMF/index.php?action=login2', data=payload)        
        # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
        f = open("ouput.html", 'wb')
        print (s.cookies)        
        #f.write(p.text.encode('utf8'))

        print ("Status Code: ", p.status_code)

        payload = {
            'test': 'testparm'
        }
        r = s.get('http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/vote_rank.cgi', data=payload)
        print (r.status_code)
        print (s.cookies)
        print (r.headers)
        f.write(r.text.encode('utf8'))
        f.close()

login_test()
```

Comment: It looks like its missing the original set-cookie response before its being redirected.  I checked with history.  Now the problem is how do you tell requests it missed a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding in the cookies manually:

```py
def login_test():
    payload = {
        'user': 'user',
        'passwrd': 'pass'
    }
    s = requests.Session()
    p = s.post('http://www.example.com/SMF/index.php?action=login2', payload, allow_redirects=False)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    #f = open("ouput.html", 'wb')    
    cookies = p.headers['Set-Cookie']
    n_cookies = {}
    m = re.compile('(\w+)=([a-z%0-9A-Z]+)[^;]*')
    for (name, content) in re.findall(m, cookies):
        if name != "expires":
            n_cookies[name] = content

    r = s.get('http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/vote_rank.cgi?mud=test', cookies = n_cookies)
```

If anyone has a better answer please add.